# How do I schedule a job in two hour interval with minutes in Quartz framework

Tags: java, cron, scheduled-tasks, quartz

I'm working on scheduled task manager based on Quartz framework. Sometimes I need to run jobs with such schedules, like "every two hours between 8:15AM and 23:59PM" (at 8:15, 10:15 etc.). I've seen some similar issues, but values of hours/minutes in this cases were known. In my case, I get it by API and must run tasks automatically.

Comment: Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this expression

> 0 15 8-23 ? * * *

At second :00, at minute :15, every hour between 08am and 23pm, of every day

**See examples of time executions:**

```
Fri Aug 16 14:15:00 UTC 2019
Fri Aug 16 15:15:00 UTC 2019
Fri Aug 16 16:15:00 UTC 2019
Fri Aug 16 17:15:00 UTC 2019
Fri Aug 16 18:15:00 UTC 2019
Fri Aug 16 19:15:00 UTC 2019
Fri Aug 16 20:15:00 UTC 2019
Fri Aug 16 21:15:00 UTC 2019
```

I used [free formatter](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html) tool to create this expression and examples.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer by @elbraulio: to make it every two hours as described in the question modify the pattern to:

```
0 15 8-23/2 ? * * *
```

The [tool](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html) describes the execution dates as:

```
Fri Aug 16 16:15:00 UTC 2019
Fri Aug 16 18:15:00 UTC 2019
Fri Aug 16 20:15:00 UTC 2019
Fri Aug 16 22:15:00 UTC 2019
Sat Aug 17 08:15:00 UTC 2019
Sat Aug 17 10:15:00 UTC 2019
Sat Aug 17 12:15:00 UTC 2019
Sat Aug 17 14:15:00 UTC 2019
```

See the [cron scheduling example](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/examples/Example3.html#Example3-CronTriggerExample).

Comment: In this case - yes, but what if the schedule is "every two hours between 8:45 and 10:15"? That pattern is not relevant then.

Comment: @alextheloafer: I don’t understand your latest comment. Could you elaborate?